# MYSQL and Hibernate: insert with default 0 instead of "null"

Tags: mysql, hibernate

I'm having troubles with inserting entities in a table. I'm using a TINYINT datatype in my columns `equal_as_expected` and `all_costs_invoiced` in table `container`

So the problems comes when I'm inserting a new container. My goal is to insert a new container and the TINYINT values for `equal_as_expected` and `all_costs_invoiced` needs to be 0 (false) by default. The problem is that if I insert a new container, the values are both set "null". This gives issues further in my program when I fetch all the containers that have `all_costs_invoiced` = false.

Can you give me some advise on how I can fix this? I've tried multiple things like:

```
ALTER TABLE container CHANGE all_costs_invoiced all_costs_invoiced TINYINT DEFAULT '0';
```

But it does not change anything, it will still insert with "null".
Also, when I tried:

```
ALTER TABLE container CHANGE all_costs_invoiced all_costs_invoiced TINYINT NOT NULL DEFAULT '0';
```

and I insert a new container it gives me a error because `all_costs_invoiced` cannot be null.

Answer (score 0):

1. change your insert statement to not insert values. This way it picks up the default value.
2. Change the table to default to 0.
3. Then `UPDATE` the `NULL`s in the table to 0.
4. Then add the `NOT NULL` constraint in table using a second `ALTER TABLE`

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but how do I change a the insert statement so it does not insert values? Right now I do not use the set method for these values before I save them with CRUD.

Comment: I don't know how hibernate does it. Are any of the answers [here](https://exceptionshub.com/how-to-set-default-value-in-hibernate.html) right?

Comment: I'll try these options and will let you know if this works.